# Proof that the closed interval in $\mathbb{R}$ is connected

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $C$ be an open and closed subset of $[a,b]$. WLOG, assume $a \in C$. Set $A = \{x \in [a,b]: [a,x] \subseteq C\}$. Since $a \in A$, sup$A$ exists.

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Then, (from real analysis), $\exists x \in A$ s.t. sup$A - \epsilon < x \leq $ sup$A$. In particular, $[a, supA- \epsilon] \subseteq C$ and so $\bigcup_{\epsilon > 0} [a, supA - \epsilon] = [a, supA) \subseteq C$.
**As $C$ is closed, $[a, $sup$A] \subseteq C$ and hence sup$A \in A$.**

--

This is the starting part of the proof and I don't get last sentence. Why does $[a,$ sup$A]\subseteq C$ because $C$ is closed?

Comment: If $B:= [a,\sup(A)) \subset C$, then $[a,\sup(A)] = \overline{B} \subset C$ because $\overline{B}$ is the smallest closed set containing $B$

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan thanks a lot. I get it now